# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-3.8

Try to open file that exists with visual Studio Code 1.43.2

This is the py file:

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

This is the result:

```
PS C:\Users\Osori> & C:/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/Osori/Desktop/python_work/9_files and exceptions/file_reader.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Osori/Desktop/python_work/9_files and exceptions/file_reader.py", line 1, in <module>        
    with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pi_digits.txt'
```

[image]

The files exists and the spelling is correct. if the file_reader.py is run with IDLE runs just fine.

[image]

Comment: `with open('c:/Users/Osori/Desktop/python_work/9_files and exceptions/pi_digits.txt') as file_object:`?

Comment: For simplicity, keep spaces out of filenames you use in coding. Not all systems (or coworkers) take kindly to it.

Comment: When OS says, the file is not there, the file is usually not there. Likely different CWD than you're expecting? Since the filename is relative to it.

Comment: _The files exists and the spelling is correct._ Then the program is checking the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

You're outside of the working directory. In the terminal, you need to

```
cd '.\Desktop\python_work\9_files and exceptions\'
```

Then run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code, allowed me to find the image by putting the absolute path instead the relative path

instead of this:

```
with open('pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

This worked:

```
with open('/python_work/9_files and exceptions/pi_digits.txt') as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

> This worked on vscode [MacOS]

```py
file_path = '/Users/osasumwenogbebor/Documents/dev/pythonCrashCourseVol2/chapter9/pi_digits.txt'
with open(file_path) as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()


print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked on windows:

```
with open(r"pi_digits.txt") as file_object:
    contents = file_object.read()
print(contents)
```

or

```
filename = "pi_digits.txt"
with open(filename) as file_object:
```